# Git pre-commit hook. Empty index behavior

Tags: git, githooks

I'm writing a pre-commit script to find binary files added to the index.

While working on it I've realized that if I add one single binary file, then do a commit, the script would unstage it(leaving the index empty) but the commit would proceed(unless I do something to prevent it).

Is this the expected behavior?

What I want to know is why do "git commit" forbid by default proceeding if index is empty, but when in a hook script the commit would be done.

For the record, I have a workaround to avoid commit to be done in cases where index is empty.

I hope someone can explain why the commit is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git *does* allow empty commits, if you use the `--allow-empty` flag.

So, what's happening here is that git starts the commit and checks for "is empty" (which would require adding `--allow-empty`) and it's not empty.  So git runs your hook, which empties out the commit, but you've already passed the "not empty" test, which is not repeated—it's up to the hook to exit nonzero in this case.

Comment: I assume this is expected behavior. It's tricky to know whether this is better than passing the "is empty" check after the pre-commit hook. Maybe I would put it after it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to check in the pre-commit hook to see if the change is empty *after* running the pre-commit processing, and how to abort the commit if nothing is changed after processing the hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... DO YOUR HOOK PROCESSING HERE...
# for example: 
# for file in `git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD | grep -iE '\.(cpp|cc|c|h|hpp|inl)$' ` ; do
#   clang-format -i -style=file ${file}
#   git add ${file}
# done

# after processing there may be no remaining (staged) changes
# so check and abort commit if nothing remains.
set +e
# Assume something remains
EXIT_CODE=0
# sets $? to 1 if anything is different
git diff-index --cached --exit-code HEAD
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # nothing remains, fail hook
  echo No changes remain after auto-format hook.  Aborting commit...
  EXIT_CODE=1
fi
exit ${EXIT_CODE}
```